# Unloading data from Snowflake to S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to unload data from Snowflake to S3:

```
copy into @my_stage/file_name.csv.gz
from (
    select * from table
    join.........
);
```

Here select statements had around 250M records :

1. Why there are multiple files created in S3 Bucket ?
2. I need to have date in suffix for file ?

Comment: it does create multiple files. For many use cases, manually setting the MAX_FILE_SIZE parameter to a large enough value will be enough to solve this.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-considerations#unloading-to-a-single-file

Comment: I don't understand the second question. Are you getting an error? please include more details of what you've tried, how you want it to work, and information about what's not working as expected.

Comment: You will have to write stored procedure to offload the file on stage if you want to have data/suffix added on the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `single=true` to your COPY INTO statement, which will work up to file sizes of 5GB.

```
copy into @my_stage/file_name.csv.gz
from (
    select * from table
    join.........
)
single=true
max_file_size=5000000000;
;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-considerations#unloading-to-a-single-file